# Having trouble while adding bootstrap in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add **bootstrap** in my plugin, while I am using **OceanWP** theme along-with. When I add Bootstrap in plugin theme `nav bar` disappears.
Following piece of code causes problem:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  wp_enqueue_style("bs_style", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
});
```

I am getting a lot of errors in console. It seems like bootstrap cdn is conflicting theme's css. Here are some of errors in console:

> Unknown property ‘-moz-opacity’. Declaration dropped. 
> widgets.css:1:34203 Error in parsing value for ‘display’. Declaration dropped. 
> widgets.css:1:34529 Error in parsing value for ‘display’. Declaration dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/506-menu-is-gone-when-using-bootstrap)!

This code to be copied into the custom.css file

```
#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you add short explanation to what this code does and how it solves the problem